# Python Flask: getting URL when moving to production

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Python from quite some time but I am totally newbie in Flask. Can you help me with two simple questions I have been strugling two days?

I have a simple Flask app that supposed to import a XLSX or CSV, parse it and create a zip file to download. While I am begginig work on the parse part, I got an error when uploading the file, and I found out that the app is not saving the file **altough it works when running flask locally**.
This is the code:

test2.py

````
``` from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

def work(arquivo):
    df = pd.read_excel(arquivo)
    return(str(df.shape))

@app.route('/')
def start():
   return "acesse /upload"


@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file():
   return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       f = request.files['file']
       f.save('./inbox/'+secure_filename(f.filename))
       a = work('./inbox/'+secure_filename(f.filename))
       return 'file uploaded successfully '+a

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```
````

And this is the upload.html file that I put on templates folder in production (the app runs on http://www.fabianocastello.com.br/test2/upload):

```
    <html>
       <body>
          <form action = "http://www.fabianocastello.com.br/test2/uploaded" method = "POST" 
             enctype = "multipart/form-data">
             <p>Arquivo</p>
             <input type = "file" name = "file" accept=".csv, .xlsx" </input>
             <input type = "submit" value="Enviar arquivo"/>
          </form>   
       </body>
    </html>
```

when locally, the upload.html file that works is this:

```
    <html>
       <body>
          <form action = "http://localhost:5000/uploader" method = "POST" 
             enctype = "multipart/form-data">
             <p>Arquivo</p>
             <input type = "file" name = "file" accept=".csv, .xlsx" </input>
             <input type = "submit" value="Enviar arquivo"/>
          </form>   
       </body>
    </html>
```

The error I got after uploading the file is this:
**Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

My questions are these:
1. Why the production app is not saving the uploaded file in "inbox" folder?
2. Is there a way that I substitute the URL in upload.html file from a variable so to I do not have to manually change the file before upload?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) method is for. That will automatically fix `"http://localhost:5000/uploader"` for you.

However, `<form action = "http://www.fabianocastello.com.br/test2/uploaded" ...>` points at a bigger misunderstanding. It would be *horrendous* if you had to alter every route in your templates moving from development to production. Your Flask routes needn't point to the specific domain that you're running your app on; they need only point to the endpoint of the server running your app (which might be `gunicorn`, for example). The [Mega Tuorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux) might be helpful here for deployment. There's also more info in the [deployment docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/).

With that out of the way, there's other issues that need to be dealt with:

1. You have two route functions with the same name - `upload_file`. Why? It doesn't matter that you decorated them with different URLs, you can't have two functions with the same name in the same namespace.
2. The *second* `upload_file` is set to accept both `GET` and `POST` requests, but you only handle the `POST` case. Sending a `GET` request to this route will error.

This fixes the form:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "{{ url_for('upload_file') }}" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <p>Arquivo</p>
         <input type = "file" name = "file" accept=".csv, .xlsx" </input>
         <input type = "submit" value="Enviar arquivo"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

This consolidates the two route functions into one:

```
@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       f = request.files['file']
       f.save('./inbox/'+secure_filename(f.filename))
       a = work('./inbox/'+secure_filename(f.filename))
       return 'file uploaded successfully '+a
   else:
       return render_template('upload.html')
```

`return 'file uploaded successfully '+a` is going to give a garbage result, if any, though. It's not going to render a template with the message, it's just going to be unstyled text. It looks like you want AJAX, which would look something like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "{{ url_for('upload_file') }}" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data" id="upload_file_form">
         <p>Arquivo</p>
         <input type = "file" name = "file" accept=".csv, .xlsx" </input>
         <input type = "submit" value="Enviar arquivo"/>
      </form>
      <div id="response_div"></div>
   </body>
   <script>
   $("#upload_file_form").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var form = $(this);
       var url = form.attr('action');

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(),
           context: form,
           success: function(resp) {
               $("#response_div").html(resp);   
           }
       });
   });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, roganjosh. I agree with your comments. Please note that this is a script that I found for "flask simple upload file" which I intend to build upon to parse the uploaded file. It is working locally with url_for, however when I host externally I got the same error, most likely because I am not being able to sabe the file It was uploaded. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @FabianoCastello firstly, you are using the _exact same code_ in production and development, now? As in, all routes just use `url_for` in the forms? How have you deployed the app?

Comment: yes, its the same code. the only place in the app I use the URL is in upload.html file and now reflects your code, incluind ajax. I am deploying the app manually in my python-based webhost, using put and ftp. I use "touch test2.swgi" to restart the app as mentioned in my webhost flask tutorial.

Comment: Can you please dump the full traceback in something like pastebin/dpaste/gist after applying my changes and link here?

Comment: this is the log: https://pastebin.com/FY4i4iNX
and this is the latest app: https://pastebin.com/b5deSrdR
upload.html is exactly the one you wrote with fixes.

Comment: @FabianoCastello well, that tells you the exact error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './inbox/sample.xlsx'`. You probably didn't make a folder called `inbox` at that location relative to the root path. I can't answer that because I don't know your app structure but that path is not pointing to what you think it does

Comment: The second link also isn't my code, because you've split `upload_file` up, which is the opposite of what I did. Get rid of the `.` in your file path if you have created a folder called `inbox` in the same folder as the flask script

Comment: taking the "." out did not work. I thank you very much for your help and I will keep trying to make this work. As I have my code more clean I might post again, counting on you! Have a great week!